# Convergence a.s. and convergence in $L^1$ don't imply each other

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to get two examples that convergence a.s. and convergence in $L^1$ don't imply each other. Now, I only know the examples that convergence a.s can't implied by convergence in probability, but don't know how to reach the above conclusion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $([0,1],\mathscr F ($borel sets on [0,1]$), m($lebesgue measure$))$

Let $X_n(x)=n1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$. This R.V. converges to 0 a.s. (it only does not converge to 0 for x=0) but $E(X_n(x)) = 1$ for every $n$ so $E(X_n) \not \rightarrow E(X) =0 $

Let $X_1=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$, $X_2=1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$, $X_3=1_{[0,\frac{1}{3}]}$, $X_4=1_{[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]}$, $X_5=1_{[\frac{2}{3},1]}$, $X_6=1_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}$ and keep continuing this pattern. $E|X_n| \rightarrow 0$ but $X_n \not \rightarrow 0$ a.s. In fact $X_n$ does not converge at all since for any $x \in [0,1] \; $ $X_n(x)$ will equal 0 and 1 for an infinite number of times